# Orchestrating multiple actions

Tags: javascript, redux

It’s unclear to me how to coordinate multiple, sequential actions in Redux. For example, I’ve got an app that has a summary panel on the left and a CRUD panel on the right. After the user CRUDs, I want the app to automatically update the summary. I also want the ability to refresh the summary and CRUD independently of each other as well. In other words, I *don’t* want the CRUD actions to have to know about the summary or any other future downstream follow-on actions (or vice versa). Is there a best practice to coordinate this without having my action creators know about other actions?

For example, here’s the (thunk) action creator for clearing a collection of entities (a CRUD action). Right, now it tightly couples the `fetchSummary()` dispatch.

```js
export function clearCollection(collection) {
    return function(dispatch) {
        dispatch(requestCollectionClear(collection));

        return doClearCollection(collection)
            .then(function(coll) { 
                dispatch(receiveCollectionCleared(coll))
            })
            .then(function() {
                dispatch(fetchSummary()); // <-- How do I chain actions without tight coupling?
            });
            // TODO: .catch()
    }
}
```

where `requestCollectionClear()` kicks off the async action and `fetchSummary()` is the action creator for the subsequent step in the workflow. What’s the best pattern to separate `fetchSummary()` from `clearCollection()`, decoupling them for use independent of each other?

Comment: Are the CRUD operations and the summary based on the same underlying data?

Comment: The CRUD operations add/edit/update entities in a collection. The summary has descriptive stats, like count by entity type across a collection. Classic master-detail-type workflow.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your answer to my question in the comment correctly (that your CRUD ops update some collection data and your summary displays some version of the same collection data), I think you can obviate your problem by thinking about your application differently.

Your state should be something along the lines of an object with a `collections` key and your reducers should operate on this object.  So a `clearCollections` method would set the `collections` value to an empty array, a `fetchCollections` method would set the `collections` value to a fresh array of data from the server, etc.

Then, your summary would just subscribe to your `store` and display the latest and greatest value for the `collections` key.  No more tight coupling.

**EDIT:** Based on the comments I think you are basically asking how to coordinate between your server and client with regard to your data.  One way of handling this is to fetch your collection data from the server on app load, then populate your Redux store with this data by dispatching an action (and passing your data to the action creator):

```
// Fetch your data
$.ajax({
  url: '/collections',
  method: 'GET',
  success: function(response) {
    // Populate your Redux store by dispatching an action
    store.dispatch(setCollections(response));
  }
});
```

Then, when you want to update your data, say add a collection, you would do something like this:

```
// Update the Redux store, which updates the UI.
store.dispatch(addCollection(someNewData));
```

Then update the server, and reconcile on response

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/collections',
  method: 'POST',
  data: {collection: someCollection},
  success: function(response) {
    // Should be a no-op b/c client has already
    // been updated.
    store.dispatch(setCollections(response))
  }
});
```

Your action creators and reducers would look like this:

```
// Action creators:
function setCollections(collections) {
  return {type: 'setCollections', collections: collections}
}

function addCollection(collection) {
  return {type: 'addCollection', collection: collection}
}

// Reducer
function reduceCollections(state = initialState, action) {
  if (action.type === 'setCollections') {
    return {collections: action.collections}

  } else if (action.type === 'addCollection') {
    return {
      collections: state.collections.concat([action.collection])
    }

  } else {
    return state
  }
}
```

How you handle all this is up to you. I've tried to keep it simple above to illustrate the point but you could use thunks for the async calls and `switch` statements or object maps for the reducers if you prefer.

Comment: The summary needs to come from the server, though, think: SELECT collection, count(*) FROM products GROUP BY collection. The client doesn't have enough information to know about all of the collections. It only knows about the updates that it just made, i.e. INSERT INTO products…. The correct summary can only be determined from the server, for example a trigger might have changed the inserted product on the way in. I think what you're suggesting is similar to what @kmcgrady suggested below. Change the client state to indicate that the collection summary is stale and listen for that.

Comment: Yes, it's expected that you need to coordinate with your server to get / update your data.  You would pull your collection data from the server on app load and then populate your Redux store with that data by dispatching an action upon data receipt.  Then, when you update your data, you update your Redux store directly on the client, fire off a server request, and then reconcile your server state with your client store in the background.  Client / server state should be the same, so it's seamless from the user's perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Approaching this with fresh eyes and more experience after three years, I’d definitely externalize the state transitions, using something like [XState](https://xstate.js.org). The state machine would keep track of the transitions and Redux would maintain the backing data, dispatching update events to components.

Answer (score 0):

To restate your problem, you want your CRUD actions to fetch a summary once they complete, but you don't want the actions to have to know about the summary.

The best way (I can think of) is to have a `stale` flag (or whatever name you'd like) in your state for the summary. In the reducer, mark the stale flag as `true` for the summary for each receive action you get from all CRUD actions. That way, the actions are not coupled, but you are guaranteed the sequential update. The summary is therefore listening for all the actions.

The next step would be to check the `stale` flag in the summary container. Assuming you are using React, I would think `componentWillUpdate` (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillupdate) would be of use. You can then trigger the `fetchSummary` action there. You also may want to do it on the initial render `componentDidMount` (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount).

Comment: “You want your CRUD actions to fetch a summary once they complete, but you don't want the actions to have to know about the summary”? (You have an extra “not” in your restatement.) I'm not using React (yet)—baby steps. For each component I have a function that updates the DOM based on the state (like React). I feel like there's a missing orchestration layer among the atomic Redux actions. Maybe that’s a job for middleware. I’ll give it some more thought. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. In the end, the summary will need to be informed of the actions. I base my from the Redux async example: https://github.com/rackt/redux/blob/master/examples/async/containers/App.js#L14 React has a little bit more of the orchestration in this case. The other option (though not as elegant) is just to wrap each action creator from the CRUD in a function that at the end sends the action to fetch the summary. Again, not as elegant, but less boilerplate.